# gRPC - Limit client requests (Throttle)

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

Is there a way to add a throttle in gRPC Unary calls? My goal is to limit each user to 10 requests per second.

In my researches I found that (maybe) it would be placed in a class that inherits Interceptor, like the following:

```
public class LimitClientRequestsInterceptor : Interceptor
{
   public override UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
            TRequest request,
            ServerCallContext context,
            UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
   {
      // Add code to limit 10 requests per second for each user.
      return await base.UnaryServerHandler(request, context, continuation);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve my problem, since gRPC does not have a built-in method (in c#) for rate limits or throttling. However, I was able to do it as shown below.

My interceptor class:

```
public class LimitClientRequestsInterceptor : Interceptor
{
   private readonly ThrottleGauge _gauge;

   public override UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
            TRequest request,
            ServerCallContext context,
            UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
   {
      var username = context.GetHttpContext().User.GetUserNameInIdentity();
      if (ThrottlingAttribute.UserHasReachedMaxRateLimit(username))
      {
         throw new RpcException(new Status(
         StatusCode.Cancelled,
         Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
         { Code = 429, Detail = $"Throttle: {username} exceeded 
         {_gauge.MaxMessagesPerTimeSlice} messages in {_gauge.TimeSlice}" })));
       }

      return await base.UnaryServerHandler(request, context, continuation);
   }
}
```

My Throttle class:

```
internal class ThrottlingAttribute
{
   private static Dictionary<string, ThrottleGauge> _byUser;
   private static TimeSpan _defaultThrottle_TimeSliceInMilliseconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ServiceSettings.Instance.DefaultThrottle_TimeSliceInMilliseconds);
   private static int _defaultThrottle_MaxMessagesPerTimeSlice = ServiceSettings.Instance.DefaultThrottle_MaxMessagesPerTimeSlice;

   public static bool UserHasReachedMaxRateLimit(string username)
   {
       ThrottleGauge gauge;
       if (!_byUser.TryGetValue(username, out gauge))
       {
           gauge = new ThrottleGauge(
               _defaultThrottle_TimeSliceInMilliseconds,
               _defaultThrottle_MaxMessagesPerTimeSlice);
               _byUser[username] = gauge;
       }

       return gauge.WillExceedRate();
   }
}
```

And my ThrottleGauge class:

```
   internal class ThrottleGauge
    {
        private readonly object _locker = new object();
        private Queue<DateTime> _Queue = new Queue<DateTime>();

        public TimeSpan TimeSlice { get; private set; }
        public int MaxMessagesPerTimeSlice { get; private set; }

        public ThrottleGauge(TimeSpan timeSlice, int maxMessagesPerTimeSlice)
        {
            TimeSlice = timeSlice;
            MaxMessagesPerTimeSlice = maxMessagesPerTimeSlice;
        }

        // returns true if sending a message now message exceeds limit rate
        public bool WillExceedRate()
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                if (_Queue.Count < MaxMessagesPerTimeSlice)
                {
                    _Queue.Enqueue(now);
                    return false;
                }

                DateTime oldest = _Queue.Peek();
                if ((now - oldest).TotalMilliseconds < TimeSlice.TotalMilliseconds)
                    return true;

                _Queue.Dequeue();
                _Queue.Enqueue(now);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```